# Access Denied while searching for the hashkey

Tags: android, facebook, cmd

To share the text via facebook in android, i installed facebook sdk in the project, then to get hashkey from **debug.keystore** gave the following line in `cmd` before the path of java

> "keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore (C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jre7\bin) | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64"

but getting "**Access Denied**" from `cmd`, what may the problem?

Comment: do you have administrator rights on your computer?